# Relational database design: User lists

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

**Background**

I'm in the process of designing a database that will allow people who have registered on my website to create lists. These lists will consist of users. The functionality will be similar to [Twitter Lists](https://media.twitter.com/best-practice/create-and-use-twitter-lists). I'm using PHP and MySQL.

**My attempt so far**

So far, I have come up with 2 tables:

**USERS**( user_id, first_name, last_name )

**LISTS**( list_id, title, description )

I now realise I need a third table which will connect the two but am struggling to come up with a list of fields it should have. My first thought was I'll need `id`, `list_id` and `user_id` fields but am unsure if this is the right approach.

**My question**

What fields will I need to create in my third table in order to be able to connect my `USERS` and `LISTS` tables?

Comment: Sidenote: It is suggested that all your tables contain a field that is relational to each (common field), which will make it easier to query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wouldn't the 3rd table serve that purpose?

Comment: I guess it would. I always like to have each table hold a field in common, but that's just me ;-)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'field in common'? Do you mean a foreign key? Perhaps you can give an example?

Comment: Take a look at http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: brilliant, thanks, I'll have a read... :)

Comment: You're welcome Henry, *cheers*

Comment: Not finished reading yet, but thanks again for this. It's a V useful resource!

Comment: In a nutshell, it depends on what kind of relationship you need, which in turns depends on your requirements. One-to-many (1:N) relationship is modeled by two tables, one of them having a foreign key towards the other. Many-to-many (M:N) is modeled by having three tables, with "junction" or "link" table in the middle, referencing both "endpoint" tables via foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is a pivot table.
You will end up with the three tables you specified already.

```
USERS(
    user_id integer not null primary key,
    first_name text not null,
    last_name text not null
 )

LISTS(
    list_id integer not null primary key,
    title text not null,
    description text,
    created_by integer references USERS
)

USERS_LISTS (
    user integer not null references USERS,
    list integer not null references LISTS,
    unique (user, list)
)
```

USER_LISTS is the the many to many glue that you need to make this work. An `id` field is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you will need:

```
Creator ID - To store the id of the user that created the list;

List ID - To store the id of the List;

User ID - To store the id of the user in that list;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of Creator ID, but wouldn't it be better to have creator_id in the LISTS table instead?

Comment: You're completly right. My mistake, the Creator ID is entirely unecessary. I believe David K-J's answer is more appropriate